# My raw image texture is rendering from a camera fine in the editor but not on build, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity 3D and am fairly competent. I have set up a raw image texture and I am using a UI image to display this texture. The texture is linked to another camera in the scene and so it displays this image(only certain layers because its just a map). Please help, I think it's something to do with frame rates and updates but I'm not to sure.

The map is on the bottom right of the screen

Editor view:

[image]

editor view (after moving around so that it is more apparent):

[image]

And here is the code for the camera, its just a simple following script.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MiniMapScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public Transform player;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, transform.position.y,player.position.z);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, player.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: it shouldnt make that difference but what build type?

Comment: Thats whats confused me, it works fine in the editor then goes all funny is the build. I thought it could be that with the optimisations that the frame rate goes up and so this problem occurs with the higher frame rate. Its build on windows 11

Comment: Ok so windows is the last thing i expected you to say.. So, the editor is not good at lets say "down grading" to more mobile like environments, so as an example i tend to do webgl things and stuff will look sweet in editor and dog crap in build because webgl doesnt run at anything like as good as windows will.  If you think its running too high a frame rate, limit the application by code to say 30fps just to see (oh and maybe ditch vsync)

Comment: Neither of those seem to work, it just appears to not be refreshing the map.

Comment: what are the settings you have on that map? have you tried other camera settings?

Comment: Ive figured it out. Everything was working fine but because the camera was only rendering the road and cars from above it just added that on top of the already existing texture. After Adding in a plane underneath the map it is working again however I would really like to not have a mini map with a solid background. Any ideas on how I could get that working?

Comment: I think it just needs to be reset every frame

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your UI did not scale correctly. When building in the editor, you can select the screen size, and on the canvas, you can change it from a constant pixel size to scale with screen size. The map in the build picture looks bigger, and the 55.77 is cut off but you might have just taken a pic like that, I would try changing the resolution and aspect ratio in the game view to see if you can recreate the problem before building.

Comment: The reason it looks bigger is because its only a part of my screen, the image was too big for stack otherwise, and it is set to scale with screen size. But my problem is more to do with the texture not updating normally

Comment: @Aidan Is there a reason to use lateUpdate over just Update, Have you tried with Update even though it won't be as in sync as easily, it should be close enough unless your moving really fast?

Comment: It had used update in my own version then I watched a brakeys tutorial and he did in in the late update, its working now but do you know if there is a way to refresh the textrue every frame?

Comment: @Aidan Last time I worked with textures I recalled the reference to the rawimage components texture and set equal to my texture in code.